# The real version of the Cuntz algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Assume that $H$ is  a real separable Hilbert space. Are there two operators $T,S \in B(H)$  which satisfy  $$TT^{*}+SS^{*}=1,\;\;T^{*}T=S^{*}S=1$$  where * is the adjoint operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In the usual case you do this with shifts, so they  work in the real case too.

Fix matrix units $\{E_{kj}\}$ and let 
$$
T=\sum_{k=1}^\infty E_{2k,k},\ \ S=\sum_{k=1}^\infty E_{2k-1,k}.
$$
Then
$$
T^*T=\sum_{k,j=1}^\infty E_{k,2k}E_{2k,j}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty E_{kk}=I, 
$$
and similarly $S^*S=I$. Also, 
$$
TT^*=\sum_{k,j=1}^\infty E_{2k,k}E_{j,2j}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty E_{2k,2k},\ \ \ 
SS^*=\sum_{k,j=1}^\infty E_{2k-1,k}E_{j,2j-1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty E_{2k-1,2k-1},
$$
so
$$
TT^*+SS^*=I.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Are there some particular properties which distinguish the real and complex Cuntz algebr?

Comment: I have no idea. In a real C$^*$-algebra you have elements with empty spectrum, for instance; without particular experience in the topic, it is hard to say what parts of the usual theory survive and which ones don't.

Comment: Is it obvious thast the series which define T or S, are norm operator convergent?

Comment: They are never norm-convergent in infinite-dimension. Either you consider the sums are sot-limits, or you consider them as just notation for the operators that are defined by their shift action on the basis elements (which leads to a bounded operator which then extends to all of $H$).

Comment: Thank you. Yes simllar to $Id=\sum_{kk}$  which is  a legal identity.However this converge in SOP.